# Python: Concatenate two dictReader strings for header row

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a header row in a results file that is the first file's header row plus second file's header row. 
For example:
Legacy file header row: (Column A, Column B ...)
Mapping file header row: (Column C, Column D ...)
and my results file should contain: (Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D) separated out with text only each each column.
I'm having trouble coming up with the proper way to concatenate the two. As you can see below the "+" is not valid. The header row will always be the first row in the file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
with open('legacyFile.csv', 'r') as in_leg, open('MappingFile.csv', 'r') as in_map, open('results.csv', 'wb') as out_res:
    c1 = csv.DictReader(in_leg, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, fieldnames=[])
    c2 = csv.DictReader(in_map, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, fieldnames=[])


    #set headers and write header row to output file
    headerList1 = list(c1)
    headerList2 = list(c2)

    c1.fieldnames = (headerList1[0])
    c2.fieldnames = (headerList2[0])
    #fieldnames = c1.fieldnames + c2.fieldnames #--> can't concatenate these
    print c1.fieldnames    
    print c2.fieldnames

    c3 = csv.DictWriter(out_res, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    c3.writeheader()

    in_leg.close()
    in_map.close()
    out_res.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the structure of `c1.fieldnames` and `c2.fieldnames`, you see that they are formatted and typed like:

```
(Pdb) c1.fieldnames
{None: ['field1', 'field2', ..., 'fieldN']}
(Pdb) type(c1.fieldnames)
<type 'dict'>
```

so we can combine these two by creating a new dictionary object that has the key of `None` and the value of the first set of `fieldnames` + the second set. We can use the line:

```
fieldnames = {None: c1.fieldnames[None] + c2.fieldnames[None]}
```

to accomplish this.

Then when you actually write out the dictionary, make sure to use the line:

```
c3 = csv.DictWriter(out_res, fieldnames=fieldnames[None])
```

instead. We need to pull the list of names out of the dictionary object.

Let me know if this works.